# Azure DevOps service connection Usage history is always empty for GitHub

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have code in GitHub and build in Azure DevOps
Build is executed nightly but Service connection Usage history is always empty for GitHub:
[image]

Any ideas how to figure out which pipelines use which service connection?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Can my answer resolves your puzzle? Feel free to let me know if you have any further concern about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure DevOps Pipelines - Get API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) can be used to fetch metadata about repo and if it's GitHub compare service connection Id with wanted, sample solution -
https://dev.azure.com/kagarlickij/_git/azuredevops-check-service-conn-usage

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas how to figure out which pipelines use which service
> connection?

Per my experience, the `execution history` there indicates the history of Github connection usage during `pipeline run` instead of `pipeline checkout`. So if we don't use the service connection in any of our task, the history would be empty.

**Some details:**

I have one pipeline which uses one private github repo as source:

[image]

Run the pipeline three times, build number `#1434`, `#1435` and `#1436`. `#1434` only has one simple CMD task while the next two runs (`#1435`,`#1436`) have extra github-related tasks which uses that github connection as task input.

`#1434`(Use the github connection in Get Source step but not in Real run process):

[image]

`#1435` and `#1436`(Call the github connection in real run process):

[image]

The result after several minutes:

[image]

For now the Guthub Connection usage history won't display the history of the pipeline run during which the connection is only used for Get Source authorization. We have to check it ourselves if any pipeline uses the connection for Get Source step.

**In addition:** I think this would be a good idea if the `usage history` can also display the history of runs that use the github connection for Get Source  Authentication step. So feel free to submit a feature request in [our User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to share your idea with the product team if you do want this feature. They would consider it seriously if it gets enough votes.

Comment: I don't wan to modify existing pipelines, maybe there's an API to fetch real service connection usage?

Comment: @kagarlickij Sorry but I'm afraid what you want is not supported for now. Most of the time the functions available in Web Portal are corresponding to those in Rest API. The corresponding API to fetch history is [Execution-history list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/executionhistory/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Just like the usage history in web portal, it only returns the history where the service connection is used in task. We don't support api to fetch the `real usage` you want so far... Sorry for the inconvenience, hope it clarifies this issue.

Comment: what about yaml pipeline deployments ? In my case, If it's a classic release then it's showing the usage history under service conneciton. But for yaml pipeline deployment, it's not showing usage entry.